# How to display a variable (here the temperature) in the console of STM32CubeIDE?

Tags: stm32, stm32ldiscovery

I'm a beginner with SMT32 products. I try to reproduce this tutoriel  which proposes how to interface with the HTS221sensor to get temperature values and display them on a terminal :

[tutorial](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15syHMqcPLt8CjpsK6ERyaiZDxn8DeYtQ)

I strictly followed the tutoriel, the building of the project is OK, but when I run the code in debug mode on the STM32L475VGT6 board and I open console -> command shell console -> nothing is displayed in this console (no temperature displayed).

Moreover when I set a variable in "Expressions", the value displayed is "Error : Target not available"...

Can you help me to solve these problems ?

my main.c code :

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; Copyright (c) 2020 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.</center></h2>
  *
  * This software component is licensed by ST under BSD 3-Clause license,
  * the "License"; You may not use this file except in compliance with the
  * License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
  *                        opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */

/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "stm32l475e_iot01.h"
#include "stm32l475e_iot01_tsensor.h"
#include <math.h>

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;
float temp_value = 0; // Measured temperature value
char str_tmp[100] = ""; // Formatted message to display the temperature value
uint8_t msg1[] = "****** Temperature values measurement ******\n\n\r";
uint8_t msg2[] = "=====> Initialize Temperature sensor HTS221 \r\n";
uint8_t msg3[] = "=====> Temperature sensor HTS221 initialized \r\n ";

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,msg1,sizeof(msg1),1000);
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,msg2,sizeof(msg2),1000);
  BSP_TSENSOR_Init();
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,msg3,sizeof(msg3),1000);

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
      temp_value = BSP_TSENSOR_ReadTemp();
      int tmpInt1 = temp_value;
      float tmpFrac = temp_value - tmpInt1;
      int tmpInt2 = trunc(tmpFrac * 100);
      snprintf(str_tmp,100," TEMPERATURE = %d.%02d\n\r", tmpInt1, tmpInt2);
      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,( uint8_t * )str_tmp,sizeof(str_tmp),1000);
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit = {0};

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_MSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIState = RCC_MSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSICalibrationValue = 0;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIClockRange = RCC_MSIRANGE_6;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_MSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_USART1;
  PeriphClkInit.Usart1ClockSelection = RCC_USART1CLKSOURCE_PCLK2;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage 
  */
  if (HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief USART1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 1 */
  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart1.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart1.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */

  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{ 
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     tex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

Thanks you,

Regards,

Lionel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thanks you for your answers.

I finally found the solution to my problem. It seems that there is a bug in the STM32Cube MX code generation tool.

In deed, although I rigorously set the pins and activate the USART1 in the "Pinout & Configuration" panel, the following piece of code is not generated in the **MX_GPIO_Init** function :

```
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};



  /*Configure GPIO pins : PB6 PB7 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF7_USART1;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);
```

So I have to copy/paste manually this piece of code in my code (main.c). Thus the global working code is the following :

```
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
  /**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; Copyright (c) 2020 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.</center></h2>
   *
   * This software component is licensed by ST under BSD 3-Clause license,
   * the "License"; You may not use this file except in compliance with the
   * License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
        *                        opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
   *
   ******************************************************************************
   */
   /* USER CODE END Header */

   /* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
   #include "main.h"
   #include "stm32l475e_iot01.h"
   #include "stm32l475e_iot01_tsensor.h"
   #include <math.h>
   #include <stdio.h>

  /* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

  /* USER CODE END Includes */

  /* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
  /* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

  /* USER CODE END PTD */

  /* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
  /* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
  /* USER CODE END PD */

  /* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
  /* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

  /* USER CODE END PM */

  /* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
  UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;
  float temp_value = 0; // Measured temperature value
  char str_tmp[100] = ""; // Formatted message to display the temperature value
  uint8_t msg1[] = "****** Temperature values measurement ******\n\n\r";
  uint8_t msg2[] = "=====> Initialize Temperature sensor HTS221 \r\n";
  uint8_t msg3[] = "=====> Temperature sensor HTS221 initialized \r\n ";

   /* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

   /* USER CODE END PV */

   /* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
  void SystemClock_Config(void);
  static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
   static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

    /* USER CODE END PFP */

  /* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
  int _write(int file, char *ptr, int len)
  {
      HAL_UART_Transmit( &huart1, (uint8_t*)ptr, len, HAL_MAX_DELAY );
      return len;
  }

  /* USER CODE END 0 */

 /**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
  int main(void)
  {
   /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

   /* USER CODE END 1 */

   /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

   /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
   HAL_Init();

   /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

   /* USER CODE END Init */

   /* Configure the system clock */
   SystemClock_Config();

   /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

   /* USER CODE END SysInit */

   /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
   MX_GPIO_Init();
   MX_USART1_UART_Init();
   /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

   HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,msg1,strlen(msg1),1000);
   HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,msg2,strlen(msg2),1000);
   BSP_TSENSOR_Init();
   HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,msg3,strlen(msg3),1000);
   printf( "Hello world!\r\n" );

    /* USER CODE END 2 */

   /* Infinite loop */
   /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
   while (1)
  {
  /* USER CODE END WHILE */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  temp_value = BSP_TSENSOR_ReadTemp();
  /* int tmpInt1 = temp_value;
  float tmpFrac = temp_value - tmpInt1;
  int tmpInt2 = trunc(tmpFrac * 100);
  snprintf(str_tmp,100," TEMPERATURE = %d.%02d\n\r", tmpInt1, tmpInt2);*/
  snprintf(str_tmp,100," TEMPERATURE = %0.4f\n\r", temp_value);
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,( uint8_t * )str_tmp,strlen(str_tmp),1000);
   }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
  }

  /**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
  void SystemClock_Config(void)
  {
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit = {0};

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_MSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIState = RCC_MSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSICalibrationValue = 0;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIClockRange = RCC_MSIRANGE_6;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
  Error_Handler();
   }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                          |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_MSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
   {
  Error_Handler();
  }
  PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_USART1;
  PeriphClkInit.Usart1ClockSelection = RCC_USART1CLKSOURCE_PCLK2;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
  {
   Error_Handler();
  }
   /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage 
  */
 if (HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1) != HAL_OK)
  {
 Error_Handler();
  }
 }

  /**
 * @brief USART1 Initialization Function
 * @param None
  * @retval None
 */
 static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
  {

 /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 0 */

 /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 0 */

 /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 1 */

 /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 1 */
 huart1.Instance = USART1;
 huart1.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
 huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
 huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
 huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
 huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
 huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
 huart1.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
 huart1.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
 {
 Error_Handler();
 }
 /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 2 */

 /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 2 */

  }

/**
* @brief GPIO Initialization Function
* @param None
* @retval None
 */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PB6 PB7 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF7_USART1;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  }

 /* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

 /* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
 * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
 * @retval None
 */
void Error_Handler(void)
 {
/* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
/* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */

/* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

 #ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
 /**
* @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
*         where the assert_param error has occurred.
* @param  file: pointer to the source file name
 * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
* @retval None
*/
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{ 
/* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
/* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
  tex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
/* USER CODE END 6 */
 }
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */

 /************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

Comment: So you have init the UART but not the pin?

Comment: In the Pinout configuration in STM32CubeMX, I have initialized the pin AND the UART. But for an unknown reason, the GPIO initialisation function was not entirely generated by the code generator. Thus, yes, to sum up, I have "init the UART but not the pin"

Answer (score 0):

There can be heaps of reasons for this.
First, you check whether you are actually connecting to the target and debugging the target.

I will give you some general debugging tips.

1. Make sure you can connect to the target and step through the code
   Make sure your wiring/electronic is correct.
2. Attach the things to the appropriate pins and everything is powered up as specified in
   datasheets.
3. Breakpoint, in your while loop, for example

> int tmpInt1 = temp_value;

in that line and make sure the values you are getting is sensible.

Otherwise, go back to step 2 and debug your electronics
    and check your code again.

Comment: What is this answer answering?

Comment: "Error : Target not available"...

Can you help me to solve these problems ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to screen your variables use USART protocol and TeraTerm program for printing values on screen. It's called as printf style debugging. Check bit rate of USART in CubeMX and Teraterm settings, they must be same.